# Presenting tk instances with Tk.mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, mainloop

I am programming a yahtzee simulator (for learning) and would like to have a few screens (tkinter instances) running at the same time but i dont want them to start at the same time and I can't figure out why they do start in the same time.

I haven't tried much except googling about it, I am new to tkinter programming...

```
from tkinter import *
Screen1 = Tk()
screen2 = Tk()

Screen1.mainloop()
```

I excpected that only screen1 would be shown but they both are being shown, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are explicitly creating two windows, so two windows appear.

You should never create more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, the second and subsequent windows need to be instances of `Toplevel`. You only need to call `mainloop` once -- it's not what creates the windows, it's simply the mechanism by which windows can respond to events. One call to `mainloop` is all you need no matter how many windows you have.

The reason for this is based on how tkinter is implemented -- tkinter is a thin wrapper around an embedded tcl interpreter (a completely different programming language environment), and each instance gets its own interpreter. That means that all of the widgets and tkinter variables (`StringVar`, etc) in one instance are invisible and inaccessible to any other instance.

If you want to create additional windows but have them hidden initially, you can call the `withdraw` method on any window you want to hide.